# Netherrack Extinguishing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft I want to make my netherrack so that when it rains it puts out the fire. This creates a more realistic view of the world and I would like to do the same thing with lava or forest fires.

How can I accomplish this naturally without me having to physically do this?

Comment: Are you open to using mods? If not, I doubt you'll have success. The extinguishing of fires is in the code. Changing it would require changing the code.

Comment: command blocks can place and put out fire (by setting the block to fire and air resp.)

Comment: FWIW:  Rain immediately extinguishes villagers that are on fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, without modification, this is not possible.  Rain is not set as conditionally capable of putting out fires.  You would either have to enable a mod, or mess with the code yourself.

I looked for some mods to give you, but was not able to find anything concrete.  I don't think that anyone has tried to implement that yet.